# Releasing registry handles faster

Tags: c#, windows, resources

C# 3.5, Windows 7+

Take the following code for example:

```
using (RegistryKey regKey = Registry.Users.OpenSubKey(regKeyString, true))
{
    if (polRegKey.GetValue("Foo") == null)
        polRegKey.CreateSubKey("Foo");
}
```

Now let's say I execute this code every second, in a loop.

When I then view the running process with Process Explorer, what I see are new handles to that registry key being generated, but not being destroyed in a timely manner.  Instead, what I see is that a new handle is created every second, then after about 20 seconds, a huge swath of almost all the handles is destroyed all simultaneously.  This is the kind of behavior I would expect from the garbage collector.  Am I wrong in thinking that C#'s `using` statement disposes of objects automatically?  It seems to do it in a very lazy way, if it's actually doing it at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You aren't disposing the value of  `polRegKey.CreateSubKey("Foo");`.

```
using (RegistryKey regKey = Registry.Users.OpenSubKey(regKeyString, true))
{
    if (polRegKey.GetValue("Foo") == null) {
        using (polRegKey.CreateSubKey("Foo")) {
            Console.Writeline("Key Created!  You could also call Dispose()!");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**[CreateSubKey()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ad51f2dx%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)** returns a **[RegistryKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)** as well.

You need to dispose of that returned object as well.